# C-1 visa, can you transfer airports?

Tags: usa, air-travel, transit-visas, layovers

I am traveling from Paraguay to Finland. My layover is in LAX. flying cheaper from John Wayne after I land in LAX.

Does anybody know if you are allowed to switch airports?

Thank you

Comment: I wonder, what are your actual origin and destination airports, and what are your travel dates? Neither Google nor Kiwi seem to suggest LAX as a connection airport (which seems legitimate given that ASU-LAX-HEL is over 50% longer than ASU-HEL).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But I’m not sure it’s a good idea.

The [Department of State website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) tells us:

> Transit (C) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons traveling in immediate and continuous transit through the United States en route to another country, with few exceptions. Immediate and continuous transit is defined as a reasonably expeditious departure of the traveler in the normal course of travel as the elements permit and assumes a prearranged itinerary without any unreasonable layover privileges (…)

You could even travel cross country before leaving the US if that is a reasonable travel plan, and you do nothing else on the way (shopping, sightseeing, visiting friends or family…).

I believe you would have to travel cross-country and change again somewhere else anyway, I don’t think there are flights to Finland directly from John Wayne airport, are there?

Note however that getting from LAX to John Wayne will take you quite some time and/or money. By public transport it takes 3 to 5 hours, and using a ride service will likely still take over an hour and set you back at least $70.

Since this most certainly involves self-transfers, you should add plenty of buffer for any issues.

Are you sure this is really a good option?

Comment: I'd also add that traffic in Los Angeles is highly unpredictable and can be grid locked for hours. It's a straight shot down I405 but traffic is bad there most of the day.